# Sed/Awk: How to iteratively concatenate lines

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following JSON. I would like to have the entire message to be read as one line. The challenge here is in my file there are thousands of below such enteries. I would like to know how I can write a script in awk or sed that would,

consider each set of flowerbrakets as one data block {....} and writes everything inside the datablock in one line (including the flowerbrackets)

```
{ 
    "technology": "big data", 
    "message" ":"A Tale Of Two Snow Queens
    It was the best of ani­ma­tion, it was the worst of ani­ma­tion. Over the next cou­ple     months, you will be able to choose for your­self which is the true Queen, and which will be the also ran. One is from #Dis­ney, and one is pro­duced in the frozen land of Rus­sia; both    are based on the clas­sic tale The #SnowQueen By #HansChris­t­ianAnder­sen and both, inter­est­ingly enough, have just released new trail­ers in antic­i­pa­tion of their pend­ing releases.
http://blog.bcdb.com/tale-snow-queens-5921/",
    "permalink":"http://www.facebook.com/BigCartoon/posts/10151959903248792","actor_id":118050938791}
```

Comment: *sigh* WHY exactly are you trying to parse JSON without a JSON parser?

Comment: newlines are not permitted in JSON strings -- should be literal `\ ` `n`

Comment: @Nirk: That's what happens when the other side doesn't use a JSON *encoder* either.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: COrrect me if I am wrong, can I install JSON Parser in Linux which would format my input to required JSON Format?

Comment: No, because no JSON parser will parse anything that's not JSON.

Comment: Trying to remove `\n` ? consider tr `tr '\n' ' ' < inputFile`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
gawk  'BEGIN {RS="{"} {gsub("\n"," "); print}'
```

Comment: this actually removes the first "{" but i think it would fit the requirement if I could the "{" back

Comment: Well, you wrote 'writes everything INSIDE the datablock in one line'... Just replace print with print "{" $0